# Image of curves in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

[image]

I'm not really sure what I'm being asked in this question. If $x=C,y=C$ doesn't that mean $z=C+iC$?

Answer (score 6):

They mean two separate problems there. Do first $x=C$; then, similarly, do $y=C$.

*EDIT*: The best way to understand this problem is with geometry, although you can of course do a bunch of algebraic computation. Note that $f(z)=\dfrac1z=\dfrac{\bar z}{|z|^2}$, so you are reflecting first across the real axis and then reflecting in the unit circle (or vice versa). If we consider the line $x=C$, then we can first reflect across the real axis, and nothing happens. The point $x=C, y=0$ maps to $u=1/C, v=0$ and the point at infinity maps to the origin. Now why do we end up with the circle symmetric about the $u$-axis passing through those two points? Consider the diagram below: Check that $\triangle OAB \sim \triangle OB'A'$. Then deduce that $\angle OA'B'$ is a right angle *always* as $A$ moves along the line $x=C$. Why does this tell you that the locus of all points $A'$ forms a circle with diameter $OB'$?
[image: Inversion]

Comment: What can I infer from $x=C$? I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Snickett What values of $z$ satisfy $x=C$?

Comment: @ErickWong $z=C+iy$. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: @Snickett Unless you already know about inversions in geometry, calculate the image of such values of $z$ under $f$.

Comment: @ErickWong  don't see how from the  starting pointing of $f(z)=\frac{1}{C+iy}$ I can get to the answer displayed in the OP. All I can do is multiply the top and bottom by the complex conjugate but that does not help at all.

Comment: @Snickett That is a separate question, your original question was that you didn't understand what the question is asking and now you do :).

Answer (score 0):

I think part (i) is a single question. They want you to find the image of the point $z=C+iC$. Otherwise it would have been split into two separate questions.

Comment: That wouldn't be a curve, would it? :)

Comment: No it's a single point, which you could regard as a degenerate curve

Comment: @DavidQuinn But from the answer given in the question itself, the image is a circle, so this isn't the desired interpretation, even if it is a possible one.

Comment: OK so they mean the image of the two straight lines $x=C$ and $y=C$. Does that make more sense?